# Make text clickable in a row, and handle overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want the string identified by the variable `location` to be clickable, and if it overflows, use the ellipsis to hide the overflowing characters. However, if `location` is short enough where the ellipsis is not needed, I don't want the remaining space in the row to be clickable

```
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
        Text('Location: '),
        Expanded(
            child: InkWell(
                onTap: () { // do something },
                child: Text(
                    '$location',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ), // Text
            ), // InkWell
        ), // Expanded
    ], // <Widget>[]
),
```

I also tried using `TextSpan` but the same thing is happening - if `location` is too short, the space to the right of it is also reacting to the tap area

```
RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
        children: [
            TextSpan(text: 'Location: '),
            TextSpan(
                text: '$location',
                recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                            ..onTap = () {
                                // do something
                            },
            ),
        ],
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the $location only clickable just **replace "Expanded" with "Flexible"**, as Flexible will shrink the widget size to its content, not to its parent's size like Expanded, e.g:

```dart
child: Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('Location: '),

    // Replace "Expanded" with "Flexible"
    Flexible(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Text(
          '$location',
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ), // Text
      ), // InkWell
    ), // Flexible
  ], // <Widget>[]
),
```